# HSQLDB creating database with properties in server.properties file

Tags: hsqldb

I want to create a database on server startup with certain properties.  I have the following in my server.properties file:

```
server.database.0=file:db;check_props=true;sql.enforce_names=true;sql.pad_spaces=false;hsqldb.default_table_type=cached;hsqldb.tx=locks;hsqldb.tx_level=serializable;hsqldb.write_delay=false
server.dbname.0=ssi
```

I don't see these reflected in the resulting db.properties file.  How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These properties are for HSQLDB 2.2.9. The properties file for version 2.x does not contain such properties. The .script file contains the equivalent SQL setting statements.

Most URL properties, including those you have used, do not apply to an existing database.

There is also an issue check_props=true, which wrongly flags the sql.pad_space property.

Comment: Thanks!  It was just worrying me that it didn't puke on invalid properties.  I feel better after validating everything in the .script file.

Comment: A new snapshot jar has just been released with a fix for the issue I mentioned at the end of the answer. See http://www.hsqldb.org/repos/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/SNAPSHOT/

Comment: May be it should be "sql.pad_space" and not "sql.pad_spaces". See http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_sql_conformance